# Pandas map multiple columns to a single dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe of surgical activity with 108 columns and 150,000 rows. Each row corresponds to a patient episode. There are 10 columns with codes for surgery procedures. 'OPERTN_01*' to '\OPERTN_10'. I want to map the code to a short text description of the surgery. I have a dictionary of the codes to their text meaning.

Here is a sample of the patient data. = test

|  | `OPERTN_01` | `OPERTN_02` | `OPERTN_03` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **`0`** | `-` | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| **`1`** | `S411` | `Z481` | `NaN` |
| **`2`** | `A024` | `Y465` | `NaN` |
| **`3`** | `L352` | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| **`4`** | `U052` | `Y981` | `NaN` |
| **`5`** | `A107` | `X654` | `NaN` |
| **`6`** | `-` | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| **`7`** | `V337` | `V551` | `NaN` |
| **`8`** | `-` | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| **`9`** | `U052` | `Y973` | `NaN` |

Here is a sample of the dictionary. = dict

```
{'A011': ' Hemispherectomy',
 'A012': ' Total lobectomy of brain',
 'A013': ' Partial lobectomy of brain',
 'A018': ' Other specified major excision of tissue of brain',
 'A019': ' Unspecified major excision of tissue of brain',
 'A021': ' Excision of lesion of tissue of frontal lobe of brain',
 'A022': ' Excision of lesion of tissue of temporal lobe of brain',
 'A023': ' Excision of lesion of tissue of parietal lobe of brain',
 'A024': ' Excision of lesion of tissue of occipital lobe of brain',
 'A025': ' Excision of lesion of tissue of cerebellum',
 'A026': ' Excision of lesion of tissue of brain stem'}
```

I have successfully merged single columns to the descriptions in the past but need to do all 10 columns.

To do the mapping I have used,

```
for col in range(1, 4):
    col_name = f'OPERTN_{col:02d}'  # Generate the correct column name (e.g., 'OPERTN_01')
```

then (to also clean up the data in case of white space etc)

```
for col in test.columns:
    test[col] = test[col].apply(lambda x: dict.get(x, x))
```

This outputs the same dataframe as 'test' above with no mapping. No errors. I have tried `na_action='ignore'`

Is this the right approach - ie to use map?.